# How to detect left click anywhere on the document using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this right now:

```
$(document).click(function(e) { alert('clicked'); });
```

In Firefox, this event is firing when I left-click OR right-click. I only want it to fire when I left-click.

Does attaching a click handler to the document work differently than attaching it to other elements? For other elements, it only seems to fire on left clicks.

Is there a way to detect *only* left clicks besides looking at e.button, which is browser-dependent?

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).click(function(e) { 
    // Check for left button
    if (e.button == 0) {
        alert('clicked'); 
    }
});
```

However, there seems to be some confusion as to whether IE returns 1 or 0 as left click, you may need to test this :)

Further reading here: [jQuery Gotcha](http://www.barneyb.com/barneyblog/2009/04/09/jquery-live-click-gotcha/)

**EDIT**: missed the bit where you asked not to use `e.button`. Sorry!

However, the example [here](http://barneyb.com/r/jquery_live_button.cfm) returns the same ID regardless of looking at it in FF or IE, and uses e.button. could possibly have updated the jQuery framework? The other answer is that older versions of IE return a different value, which would be a pain. Unfortunately I only have IE 7/8 here to test against.

Comment: It looks like the click handler functions differently depending on the element it's attached to. For the document element, it handles both left and right clicks, so there doesn't seem to be any way around checking e.button.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply register for a "contextmenu" event like this:

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
    return false;
});
```

Taken from: http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/8-awesome-jquery-tips-and-tricks

Comment: e.preventDefault(); is better practice instead of return false.
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 0):

I've read that if you bind with "live" in jQuery 1.3, jQuery normalizes the click between browsers. I've not tested this.

However, this would indicate that it doesn't: http://abeautifulsite.net/notebook/99

Since you say click works correctly everywhere but on "document," have you tried a 100% div over the document to catch the click?

Answer (score 0):

There is no not-browser-dependent way to detect only left-clicks. You can use this code that works under IE and non-IE browsers:

```
$("#element").live('click', function(e) {

    if( (!$.browser.msie && e.button == 0) || ($.browser.msie && e.button == 1) ) {

        // Left mouse button was clicked (all browsers)

    }

});
```

Taken from: http://abeautifulsite.net/notebook/99